# Removing white inner border from combobox

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have this simple combobox style:

```
<Style TargetType="ComboBox">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="GhostWhite"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#007acc"/>
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="#49494e"/>
</Style>
```

I am trying to remove that white inner border which you can see in the picture bellow, between the blue border and the gray background.

So far nothing I tried with setters works. Is there any compact way to do so?

[image: Combobox]

Comment: Did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11528446/changing-the-border-colors-of-a-wpf-combobox)?

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove your style from the `ComboBox`.
2. Right click on the `ComboBox` in the designer and select "Edit Template\Edit A Copy..."
3. Use the screen which pops up to place the style template somewhere you can find it.
4. Change all the `BorderBrush` properties to the color you are looking for.

If this does not work for you then add a comment to this answer.

Comment: I did this, I changed every single color there to red as a test and the only things that remained their default colors was that black arrow, gradient background color of the combobox on mouseover and that cursed border.

Comment: @user3595338 can you add the template to your question?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to retemplate the combobox.

Comboboxes contain a ToggleButton, which is where the white border you're seeing comes from. You can see the default ToggleButton style (and offending Background property on line 65) here: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296245(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc296245%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)